# RegEx for Phone Number Numbers with Letters

Tags: php, regex, formatting, phone-number

I need to format a phone number as one long string of numbers (US Phone Number format)

```
// I know there are tons more
$phones = array(
    '1(800) 555-1212',
    '1.800.555.1212',
    '800.555.1212',
    '1 800 555 1212',
    '1.800 CALL NOW' // 1 800 225-5669
);

foreach($phones as $phone) {
    echo "new format: ".(preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $phone)."<br />\n";
}
```

Now this should return something like this:

```
8005551212 (with or without the 1)
```

but how do I map/convert the number with CALL NOW to:

```
18002255669
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `strtr()`.

```
$number = strtr($number, array('A'=> '2', 'B' => '2', ... 'Z' => '9'));
```

Or actually, I think:

```
$number = strtr($number, "AB...Z", "22...9");
```

Answer (score 4):

To save some typing...

```
$phoneNumber = strtr($phoneLetters, "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", "22233344455566677778889999");
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first step, you need to do a different regex replace (your version would now lose all the letters):

```
$result = preg_replace('/[^A-Z0-9]+/i', '', $phone);
```

Then, you need to take the string and replace each letter with its corresponding digit (see konforce's answer). That's not really a job for a regex.