# JS - Regex against Telephone Numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I am doing a simple cleanup of phone numbers on my web pages,

In many cases I see human friendly phone numbers, like **1-800**-CONTACTS.
My current scripting strips out everything except the numbers.

```
var theValueNumOnly = $.trim($(this).text()).replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
```

The value becomes: **1800**

Does anyone know a simple snippet that already had the letters-to-numbers converted?

Comment: No, but it's not hard to create a mapping...you might want to use the callback version of `replace` and just pass the letters through a lookup dict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var toPhoneNumber = (function () {
    var dict = {
        a: 2, b: 2, c: 2,
        d: 3, e: 3, f: 3,
        g: 4, h: 4, i: 4,
        j: 5, k: 5, l: 5,
        m: 6, n: 6, o: 6,
        p: 7, q: 7, r: 7, s: 7,
        t: 8, u: 8, v: 8,
        w: 9, x: 9, y: 9, z: 9
    }

    return function (str) {
        return str.toLowerCase().replace(/[^\da-z]/g, '').replace(/([a-z])/g, function (v) {
            return dict[v];
        });
    }
}());
```

To use it, just pass your string to the `toPhoneNumber` function:

```
var phoneNumber = toPhoneNumber('1-800-CONTACTS');
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ReGYp/1/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a post on his topic [RegEx for Phone Number Numbers with Letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331721/regex-for-phone-number-numbers-with-letters) that provides a PHP solution.  You could do this in a regex by mapping each of the 24 letters that convert to numbers.  It's probably easier in PHP or python or your favorite language.

Answer (score 0):

The direct approach (handles upper and lower case):

```
phone = "1-800-CONTACS"

phone = phone.replace(/[abc]/gi,  '2');
phone = phone.replace(/[def]/gi,  '3');
phone = phone.replace(/[ghi]/gi,  '4');
phone = phone.replace(/[jkl]/gi,  '5');
phone = phone.replace(/[mno]/gi,  '6');
phone = phone.replace(/[pqrs]/gi, '7');
phone = phone.replace(/[tuv]/gi,  '8');
phone = phone.replace(/[wxyz]/gi, '9');
phone = phone.replace(/[^0-9]/g,  ' ');

console.log(phone)
=> 1 800 2668227
```

Comment: An it can easily be turned into a function if you want to.